# How to wait for all promises being added to array in forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like my function to return array of promises. The code inside the function is asynchronous. I need to check each element for its type and do some processing. I do not know how the function can return all promises - once it has done the asynchronous processing. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gjcbvv2/)

```
function addFeatures (input) {

  var result = [];
  input.forEach(function (el) {

    if (Number.isInteger(el)) {
      // placeholder asynchronous
      setTimeout(function () {
        result.push(
          new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(el.toString() + 'string')
          })
        )
      }, 2000);
    } 
    else {
      // placeholder synchronous
      result.push(
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          resolve(el + 'string')
        }));
    }
  })
  return result;
};

var arr = [1, 'text']
var final = addFeatures(arr)
// should log 2 promises but logs only 1 - the synchronous
console.log(final)
```

Comment: You cant return 2 of them, coz you are using setTimeout to push one of them to the array. Instead of that, you should use setTimeout inside the promise, so that it will resolve after 2seconds and you will get both promises returned from your function

Comment: You are right. I hope I can somehow make it work with the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is to create the promise immediately and do the asynchronous stuff *inside* of it:

```
function addFeatures (input) {
  var result = [];
  input.forEach(function (el) {
    result.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (Number.isInteger(el)) {
        // placeholder asynchronous
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(el.toString() + 'string')
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        // placeholder synchronous
        resolve(el + 'string')
      }
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

I would also recommend to use `map` instead of `forEach`+`push`.

Comment: + you'd want to `return Promise.all(result)` so that the function returns a single Promise

Comment: @Thomas OP said he wants his "*function to return array of promises*". I guess he's going to call `Promise.all` on the return value, but one could also do some postprocessing on the individual promises.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the excellent answer from Bergi, this is my contribution:

1- Function `addFeatures` with `array.map`:

```
function addFeatures (input) {
    return input.map(function(el) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (Number.isInteger(el)) {
                setTimeout(resolve, 2000, el.toString() + 'string');
                /* setTimeout(reject, 2000, el.toString() + 'string'); //for reject */
            }
            else {
                resolve(el + 'string');
                /* reject(el + 'string'); //for reject */
            }
        })
    });
};
```

2- A function to test the result from `addFeatures`.

If you don't **manage correctly** the answer from code above, **sometimes** the `resolve` from the `asynchronous placeholder promise` becomes `pending` and returns `undefined`. That's why you need `Promise.all`:

```
function foo(){
    return Promise.all(addFeatures([1, 'text'])).then(values => {
        return values;
    }, function() {
        throw 'Promise Rejected';
    });
}
```

3- Calling your function above

```
foo().then(function(result) {
    console.log("result => " + result);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error => " + error);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gjcbvv2/6/)